# Extracting direction changes from a list of coordinates

Tags: c#, linq

Given a list of coordinates, what would be the most efficient way to determine the direction changes?

[image: Path of coordinates]

What I have currently tried:

```
        List<Point> path = GetRoute();

        List<Point> pointsToKeep = new List<Point>();

        pointsToKeep.Add(path.First());

        int previousX = path.First().X;
        int previousY = path.First().Y;

        foreach (var item in path)
        {
            int diffY = (item.Y - previousY);
            bool up = diffY > 0;
            bool down = diffY < 0;

            if (up || down)
            {
                pointsToKeep.Add(item);
            }

            previousX = item.X;
            previousY = item.Y;
        }
```

Ideally would want the all the points highlighted in Orange to be added to the pointsToKeep list

As the path is going from Left to Right, the X coordinate will never decrease

Comment: What's the problem with the code you already have? Does it not work? Does it not work *fast enough*? I don't think there's any special algorithm for this problem, so you're probably limited to a few potential micro-optimizations.

Comment: your code will add all the vertical points

Comment: @theodoros-chatzigiannakis its currently giving me all the vertical points, I get the first coordinate added correctly and also the second, however as its going up in a vertical line, I'm getting all the interim points added.

Comment: @hadi-hassan Correct, also have a problem with the points going in diagonal directions

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. In that case, the problem is that you aren't carrying all the information you need across the loops. Knowing the previous point isn't enough - you need to know the previous *direction*, which means you need to keep track of the sign of the difference (both in the X and in the Y axis) and see if it's maintained. Add to the list only those points where you have a change of the sign. Is this enough to get you going?

Comment: This definitely helps, the previous direction was the missing part, thanks

Comment: Just to add to the discussion, I think you will need 3 points(A,B,C) to be sure about direction changes; then use the slopes of AB and BC, and you can take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of not just the previous point, but the *direction* that you took to arrive at that previous point. If you squint a little, you could say that this is analogous to why [you need derivatives to find the relative minimum and relative maximum](http://www.themathpage.com/acalc/max.htm) in the plot of a function *f(x)*.

Now back to your case. Assuming your possible directions are at 0, 45 or 90 degrees, then just keeping track of two signs should be more than enough to represent all possible slopes. (If my assumption doesn't hold for your case, you need to keep track of something more detailed than just the sign.)

All that being said, you probably need something like this:

```
        var previous = path.First();
        var direction = new Point(0, 0);

        foreach (var item in path)
        {
            var signX = Math.Sign(item.X - previous.X);
            var signY = Math.Sign(item.Y - previous.Y);

            if (signX != direction.X || signY != direction.Y)
            {
                pointsToKeep.Add(previous);
            }

            previous = item;
            direction = new Point(signX, signY);
        }
```

Note that if you add `item` to the list, you're keeping track of the first point of the *new* direction, while if you add `previous` to the list, you're keeping track of the last point of the *previous* direction. (I believe you'll probably want to keep `previous`, but see it for yourself.)

Comment: this code sample and the provided link has helped alot, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
    List<Point> path = Point.GetData();
    List<Point> pointsToKeep = new List<Point>();
    var current = path[0];
    var currentDiffX = 0;
    var currentDiffY = 0;
    foreach (var point in path)
    {
        var diffX = point.X - current.X;
        var diffY = point.Y - current.Y;
        if (diffX != currentDiffX || diffY != currentDiffY)
            pointsToKeep.Add(current);
        current = point;
        currentDiffX = diffX;
        currentDiffY = diffY;
    }
    // add the last point
    pointsToKeep.Add(path[path.Count-1]);
    foreach(var point in pointsToKeep)
        Console.WriteLine("Ponint({0}.{1})",point.X,point.Y);
```

for more accurate result

-you can track the slope ( y2- y1)/(x2-x1) and once the slope changes, then add the point

here a working [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TdgyVn)

Comment: Thanks for the demo and the pointer to tracking the slope change